# Converting GeoNames csv file to shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, convert, geonames

How can I convert a Geonames csv file (downloaded from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) to a ShapeFile?

Comment: With which GIS software would you like to accomplish this task?  Without any software constraints, there's probably hundreds or even thousands of ways from which to choose. Please update the question.

Comment: Yes, with GIS software / tools, without any constraints. I am looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

On the [Geonames Libraries/Tools Page](http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html) you find a list of tools, that convert the csv file of GeoNames directly to a shapefile...

Answer (score 2):

If yo have ArcGIS (ESRI), this might be an option:

- Choose File/Add X/y-Data
- Select Geonames.org csv (with extension *.txt)
- Choose the lat/lng fields containing X and Y values, e.g. for cities1000.csv the selection would look like this:

[image]

- Select WGS1984 as the coordinate system
- Export layer as Shapefile (project if you need to)